# naming elements of a list in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

I am new to R. I just started 2 days ago, I was following along  with my instructor on the topic of naming list. I had seen an example done, and decided to do on my own.

```
list('Chicago' = 1, 'New York' = 2, 'Los Angeles' = 3)

$Chicago
```

Every time I run this code I keep getting the error message Error: unexpected '$' in "$"
I was trying to print out 1, the numeric stored in Chicago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign your list to a name to access it again.

```r
mylist <- list('Chicago' = 1, 'New York' = 2, 'Los Angeles' = 3)

mylist$Chicago
# [1] 1
```

Comment: or `.Last.value$Chicago`